# SSD Causing Battery To Die Almost Instantly?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, ssd, battery

I'm a little stumped a what the problem is. I recently got a used a laptop and I swapped out the 500GB 5400RPM hard drive for a PNY 120GB SSD drive. When I unplug the power from the laptop, the battery charge (according to Windows 7) goes from 100% to 4-6% in less then a minute. I'm wondering if this might have something to do with SSD, but its my understand that a solid state drive using very little (if any) power. So is it the SSD or battery causing it to go dead? The laptop is a Gateway NV59 with Intel Core i3 330M and 4GB RAM.

Comment: Just for a sanity check, if you swap back in the 500GB drive does the battery not display as drained so quickly? Personally, I don't trust used laptop batteries at all. Who knows how the previous owner abused it.

Comment: @beeks I guess I could try putting it back. Whats weird too is my battery went from 21% to 100% in no time.

Comment: Sounds like you need a new battery, to be honest.

Comment: Hasn't been dropped a small screw into the laptop bowels causing the shorting and current leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I installed the SATA drive back into the laptop. Because I formatted it when I replaced it with the SSD, I had to reinstall Windows 7. Once I reinstalled Windows, it came up in the notification area saying the battery was bad. I put the SSD back into it and started up Windows, where the notification area didn't say anything about the battery being bad. What I didn't notice was if you click the battery icon, there's a checkbox (as shown below) that when checked, will show if the battery is bad or not. I wonder if the previous owner that I bought it from unchecked it (as its checked by default) to try and make the new owner (me) think that the battery is fine. Anyway, I contacted the previous owner and he gave me a partial refund to cover the cost of a new battery.

[image: Checkbox in Windows to show if battery is bad]